# RewriteRule rules order and flags

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a problem with RewriteRule flags. I have a "main" RewriteRule that handles my application, but I also have some urls that need to be handled differently (see them as custom routes).

I've tried many different flags, but it never gives me the result I want. Check the first comment in the code for what I want.

```
# First check if this pattern is found, and if it's not, continue to the next one and disregard this one
RewriteRule ^test/report/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=report&id=$1 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the C flag, for chaining, on your first rule, which means that the second rule will be disregarded if the first does not match.  Your comment describes what would happen without the C flag.  I think you may want an L flag instead if you want to avoid applying the second rule if the first rule matches.

**Edit:**

Now that you've changed the C flag to L on your first rule, there is another issue.  You need to ensure that a rewritten path does not get re-processed by your RewriteRule directives in some way that will change it.

In this case, one way to accomplish that goal is to ensure that the page itself is not already rewritten to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^test/report/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=report&id=$1 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
```

Unfortunately, I do not know of a way to make the same RewriteCond apply to all your rules other than repeating it before each one.

**Edit:**

Now that I think of it, yes, there is possibly a somewhat better solution.  Instead of using the RewriteCond directives, start with:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php - [PT,NC,L]
```

Now, anything starting with index.php will match, nothing changes, and no more RewriteRules will be followed.

Comment: True, I forgot to remove the C flag. Removing it or replacing it with the L flag results in a page parameter that is always 'index.php'. Very weird

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work but there should be a better solution don't you think?

Comment: Lord Andrew, you rule! Thanks a bunch

Comment: But now I can only access index.php from that directory and all paths of my js, css files are now broken

Comment: @Jesse Yes, those would be mapping to index.php also under your current rules.  If you add "exceptions" for them similar to what you added for index.php, that should take care of it.  Let me know if you need an example, but it would basically be another RewriteRule that matches js or css files and (using the - operator that was used in the index.php rule) does not rewrite them.

Comment: That's too bad, but it's worth it. I did it like this: `RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ js/$1 [PT]`. Thanks again